# emacs: mode hook is bypassed when mode is switched by hand

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

In my `.emacs` there is the following mode hooks:

```lisp
(defun my-html-mode-hook ()
  (interactive)
  (setq tab-width 4
        ;; this will make sure TABs are used instead of spaces
        indent-tabs-mode t)
  )

(defun my-javascript-mode-hook ()
  (interactive)
  (setq tab-width 4
        ;; this will make sure TABs are used instead of spaces
        indent-tabs-mode t)
  )


(add-hook 'javascript-mode-hook 'my-javascript-mode-hook)
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'my-html-mode-hook)
```

Now when I am opening a `.html`, it works as expected, same for opening `.js`.

However, when opening `.html` and then switching to JavaScript by `M-x javascript-mode` by hand, `my-javascript-mode-hook` is **not** run (at least tab width switches to 8). How to make that hook run when I switch the mode manually?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `javascript-mode-hook`, I'm afraid.  Certainly not by default.

`javascript-mode` is an *alias* for `js-mode`, meaning that only `js-mode-hook` is defined.  However, variable aliases are also a thing -- I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` and ask whether `javascript-mode-hook` might be defined as a variable alias for `js-mode-hook`.  So long as that `defvaralias` was autoloaded (along with the mode's alias, and hence before you've used it), I believe it would work as desired.

As such, and as I expected, I am unable to reproduce/confirm your assertion that `javascript-mode-hook` "works as expected" in the case of opening a `.js` file.  Your code does not behave that way in either Emacs 26.3 or 27.0.90.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a dreaded ambiguity in naming, namely both `javascript-mode-hook` and `js-mode-hook` are recognized and run on startup when a JavaScript file is opened.

However, when switching to JavaScript by hand, only `js-mode-hook` is run.  Both `js-mode` and `javascript-mode` mode trigger `JavaScript` mode (at least they are displayed as `(JavaScript)` in the status line), so someone got tired of typing the "avacript" letters and kicked them out of "javascript" but forgot to clean up some mess...